# Function as an argument to a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to implement a function that takes another function as an argument, and returns a new version of that function that can only be called once.

Subsequent calls to the resulting function should have no effect (and should return undefined).

For example:

```
logOnce = once(console.log) 
logOnce("foo") // -> "foo" 
logOnce("bar") // -> no effect
```

Comment: Do you have a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to illustrate your question? Because as is, we cannot understand it...

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: He want's a function who can run only one time.

Comment: Is `once(console.log, "foo");` ok? Than it's easier.

Comment: here function once has the argument console.log, which is assigned to to the logOnce. So if i call logOnce("foo") it should return me same functionality as console.log("foo") does. But this should be invoked only once.

Comment: @AndreasFurster ty for you reply, nope it should take only the function as an argument the value will be passed when it's invoked with the other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag on the function obeject you are passing as argument

```js
function once(func){
  return function(){
    if(!func.performed){
      func.apply(this,arguments);
      func.performed = true;
    }    
  }
}

var logOnce = once(console.log);
logOnce("Test 1");
logOnce("Test 2");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it should run only once, second time should do nothing(or return undefined).

Comment: The second time it doesn't log infact